# How to get a Map value inside for loop?

Tags: apex, map

I have a Map. When I try to get a value of the map it is not coming inside for loop.

```
Map<VEH_Vehicle__c,CST_Carset__c> VehSerQuery=getQuerySevice(VehResQuery);
```

code

```
public static Map<VEH_Vehicle__c, CST_Carset__c> getQuerySevice(Map<String, VEH_Vehicle__c> mapResponse) {

  Map<VEH_Vehicle__c, CST_Carset__c>  mVehService = new Map<VEH_Vehicle__c, CST_Carset__c>();

  //harvest ids
  Set<Id> setCarsetId  =  new Set<Id>();
  for (String strVin : mapResponse.keyset() )  {
    VEH_Vehicle__c oVeh = mapResponse.get(strVin) ;
    setCarsetId.add(oVeh.UnitOrder__r.CarSet__r.id);
  }
  Map<Id, CST_Carset__c> mCarset = new Map<Id, CST_Carset__c>(
       [SELECT Id, 
                  (SELECT Code__c, Label__c, ServiceType__c 
                   FROM Services__r) 
        FROM CST_Carset__c 
        WHERE Id IN:setCarsetId ]);

  for (String  strVin : mapResponse.keyset() ) {
    VEH_Vehicle__c oVeh = mapResponse.get(strVin) ;
    CST_Carset__c lServices = mCarset.get(oVeh.UnitOrder__r.CarSet__r.id);
    mVehService.put(oVeh, lServices);
  }

  return mVehService ;
}
```

Here VehSerQuery size is 4.Having both key and values''

**result**

```
VehSerQuery{
    VEH_Vehicle__c:{UnitOrder__c=a0I4E000000UJEWUA4, DueDate__c=2016-12-30 00:00:00, DepreciationDate__c=2016-08-11 00:00:00, BillingDate__c=2016-08-26 00:00:00, BlockedInvoice__c=B, RegistrationNumber__c=RN9684, VehicleOrderNumber__c=V9684, KeyCode1__c=KC9684, CarRadioCode__c=R697, BCVEnergy__c=EN1, BCVIndexPollution__c=IP1, VINNumber__c=VN15RB20A55579085, Id=a0N4E0000010V4IUAU}=CST_Carset__c:{Id=a074E000000fvVBQAY}, 
    VEH_Vehicle__c:{UnitOrder__c=a0I4E000000UGw1UAG, DueDate__c=2016-12-30 00:00:00, DepreciationDate__c=2016-08-11 00:00:00, BillingDate__c=2016-08-26 00:00:00, BlockedInvoice__c=B, RegistrationNumber__c=RN19, VehicleOrderNumber__c=V19, KeyCode1__c=KC19, CarRadioCode__c=R19, BCVEnergy__c=EN1, BCVIndexPollution__c=IP1, VINNumber__c=VG1JZ49BJ55611173, Id=a0N4E0000010VgfUAE}=CST_Carset__c:{Id=a074E000000fveNQAQ}, 
    VEH_Vehicle__c:{UnitOrder__c=a0I4E000000UI90UAG, DueDate__c=2016-12-30 00:00:00, DepreciationDate__c=2016-08-11 00:00:00, BillingDate__c=2016-08-26 00:00:00, BlockedInvoice__c=B, RegistrationNumber__c=RN5213, VehicleOrderNumber__c=V5213, KeyCode1__c=KC5213, CarRadioCode__c=R222, BCVEnergy__c=EN1, BCVIndexPollution__c=IP1, VINNumber__c=VN1RFC00555850061, Id=a0N4E0000010TZjUAM}=CST_Carset__c:{Id=a074E000000fveNQAQ}, 
    VEH_Vehicle__c:{UnitOrder__c=a0I4E000000UIwqUAG, DueDate__c=2016-12-30 00:00:00, DepreciationDate__c=2016-08-11 00:00:00, BillingDate__c=2016-08-26 00:00:00, BlockedInvoice__c=B, RegistrationNumber__c=RN5813, VehicleOrderNumber__c=V5813, KeyCode1__c=KC5813, CarRadioCode__c=R822, BCVEnergy__c=EN1, BCVIndexPollution__c=IP1, VINNumber__c=VN1RFB00555029195, Id=a0N4E0000010TjPUAU}=CST_Carset__c:{Id=a074E000000fveNQAQ}
}
07:55:53.3 (155641250)|USER_DEBUG|[47]|DEBUG|<<<<<<VehSerQuery.size 4
```

While try to get the value of CST_Carset__c am not able to get the value

**apex**

```
for(VEH_Vehicle__c Veh:VehSerQuery.keyset()) {
    system.debug('<<<<<<Inside for loop VehSerQuery'+VehSerQuery.keyset() +':::'+VehSerQuery.values());
    system.debug('## Vehiclle ---- ::'+ Veh);
    system.debug('## VEH::'+ VehSerQuery.get(Veh));
}
```

Inside ## VEH:: is empty !!
I am not able to get the value of specific key !!

Comment: Do you really need to entire object as the key?

Comment: Yes. I need the entire object and i passes this value to some method and i will use

Comment: Oh and the Vehicle value is there in the loop?

Comment: It would be common to use 2 maps here, one of VEH_Vehicle__c keyed by its Id and another of CST_Carset__c keyed by its Id. (Assuming there is a related Id field between the two objects else a third map to relate the objects by Id.) That avoids unexpected results - such as not being able to lookup in a map - when e.g. a value is changed in one of the objects.

Comment: yes.Inside the for loop in the first debug am getting the values correctly.But in the VEH only am not getting values:(

Comment: @KeithC I have done it in that way in a method.Could you suggest me some way to come out from this

Comment: You could also use the map.values() to get the id

Comment: @CasparHarmer Using map.values() how can i get the specific Id of that value

Answer (score 1):

Create a new subclass - say `QueryServiceResult` it would look something like this:

```
public class QueryServiceResult{
    Map<Id, VEH_Vehicle__c> vehiclesByIdMap {get;set;}
    Map<Id, CST_Carset__c> carsetsByVehicleIdMap {get;set;}

    public QueryServiceResult(){
        vehiclesByIdMap = new Map<Id, VEH_Vehicle__c>();
        carsetsByVehicleIdMap = new Map<Id, CST_Carset__c>();
    }
}
```

Then, in the your final loop in the `getQuerySevice` method, change it to:

```
QueryServiceResult qsr = new QueryServiceResult();

for (String  strVin : mapResponse.keyset() ) {
    VEH_Vehicle__c oVeh = mapResponse.get(strVin) ;
    CST_Carset__c lServices = mCarset.get(oVeh.UnitOrder__r.CarSet__r.id);

    qsr.vehiclesByIdMap.put(oVeh.Id,oVeh);
    qsr.carsetsByVehicleIdMap.put(oVeh.Id,lServices);
} 

return qsr;
```

(Your will need to change the return type of your method to `QueryServiceResult`)

Finally, in the outer loop, extract the values like this:

```
for(Id vehicleId : qsr.vehiclesByIdMap.keyset()) {
    VEH_Vehicle__c vehicle = qsr.vehiclesByIdMap.get(vehicleId);
    CST_Carset__c carSet = qsr.carsetsByVehicleIdMap.get(vehicleId);
}
```

A word of advice. Name your variables very carefully. Minimize abbreviations. It will make your code easier to read.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of abbreviations at the moment - and a horrible predilection  to make every second class some sort of "Helper". Drives me crazy.